# How to add "Apple touch icon" in a magento store version 1.9.4.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, icon

I want to add an apple-touch icon in my Magento store which has version 1.9.4.0
I have googled but there was no usable and correct tutorial or guidance! does anyone have the same experience or something to share to help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://www.example.com/custom_icon.png">` in your `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to edit your local.xml file in your theme to include it like this

```
<action method="addLinkRel">
<rel>apple-touch-icon</rel>
<href>apple-touch-icon.png</href>
```

Answer (score 0):

System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head Miscellaneous Scripts. Then add